# Minkowski's inequality

Tags: inequality, summation

Minkowski's inequality for sums states $$\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty |a_j+b_j|^2 \right)^{1/2} \le \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty |a_j|^2 \right)^{1/2}+\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty |b_j|^2 \right)^{1/2} $$ for $\mathbb{C}^n$ in the Euclidean norm. How may I show that, in a weighted sequence space $\ell_\beta^2$, $$\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty |a_j+b_j|^2 \beta(j)^2 \right)^{1/2} \le \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty |a_j|^2 \beta(j)^2 \right)^{1/2}+\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty |b_j|^2 \beta(j)^2 \right)^{1/2}$$
Initially, I tried simplifying the LHS as $\beta(j) ( \sum_{j=0}^\infty |a_j+b_j|)^{1/2}$ but that is an illegal move (can't move $\beta(j)$ out of the summation).

Comment: Shouldn't $\beta(j)$ be squared in the LHS?

Comment: All the $\beta(j)$ are non-negative? And by the way, you have a weight of $\beta(j)$ on the left and $\beta(j)^2$ on the right, should be the same exponent on both sides. Anyway, do you know that Minkowski's inequality holds for all positive measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sequence of weights $\beta=(\beta(j))_j$ consists only of non negatives numbers, follow the next hint

**HINT** Apply minkowski's inequality to the sequence 
$$
a\beta + b\beta = ( a_j \beta(j) + b_j \beta(j) )_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^2
$$
To obtain that in fact 
$$
\|a\beta + b\beta \|_2 \leq \|a\beta \|_2 + | b\beta \|_2
$$
Where
$$
\|a\|_2=\left( \sum_{j=1} |a_j|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$